# How to put a delay in loading of images in the same area to make it look like an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have like 2 images, and I want to show one for 3 seconds, then replace it with another, in the same img tag.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
    $("#image_area").hide();
    $('#W40').click(function(){
        $("#image_area img").remove();
        show_image_area('40');
    });     
});
```

So the flow is first hide the #image_area, then when #W40 button is clicked, remove any current image in the area and run the show_image_area function, the function is as follows:

```
function show_image_area(world){
    if (!$("#image_area img").length) { //only run if no current image exists   
        $('#image_area').show();
        $('#image_area').prepend("<img id='tw_image' src='world+"/7.png' width=\"1000\" height=\"1030\" />");
        setTimeout($("#tw_image").attr("src", "world+"/8.png"), 3000);  
    }
}
```

Right now, if I run these code, the 8.png shows almost immediately, and there are no 3 second delay that I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra " in the code: should be `$("#tw_image").attr("src", world+"/8.png")`.

Also, I would put `$("#tw_image").attr("src", world+"/8.png")` in a function of it's own.

```
function SwapImage(world)
{
    $("#tw_image").attr("src", world+"/8.png");
}
```

Then change your last line to `setTimeout(SwapImage(world), 3000);`

Comment: Thanks guys, every answer was good, looks like this one was the quickiest, so I selected this one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isnt fully tested but gives you an idea:

```
$(function(){
    $("#image_area").hide();
    $('#W40').click(function(){
        $("#image_area img").remove()
        show_image_area('40');
    });
});

function show_image_area(world){    
    var newImg = $('<img />').css({width: 1000, height: 1030}).attr({id: 'tw_image', src: world+'/7.png');
    if ( !$("#image_area img").length ) { //only run if no current image exists   
        $('#image_area').prepend(newImg).show('fast');
        setTimeout( function() {
            $("#tw_image").attr("src", world+"/8.png");
        }, 3000);  
    }
}
```

Basically yours was immediately firing the setTimeout function instead of passing in a function to be fired later

Answer (score 0):

That's because the first parameter of setTimeout is not a function.
Also there is an extra quote on that line.
Also, the "world" variable might need closure (can't remember).
Try

```
function show_image_area(world){
    if (!$("#image_area img").length) { //only run if no current image exists   
        $('#image_area').show();
        $('#image_area').prepend("<img id='tw_image' src='world+"/7.png' width=\"1000\" height=\"1030\" />");
        var myWorld = world;
        setTimeout(function () {$("#tw_image").attr("src", myWorld+"/8.png");}, 3000);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) call is a bit off:

```
setTimeout($("#tw_image").attr("src", "world+"/8.png"), 3000);
```

The first argument should be the function to execute:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#tw_image").attr("src", "world/8.png") }, 3000);
```

Also, I'm not sure what "world" is so I merged it into the new `src` path to fix a stray double quote.